# SQL Server query to find records with gap or 12 months or greater

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of records, each record has a created date and a userid.

I am trying to find all records where there has been a gap of 12 months or greater between records for that given user. Which is the most simplest method to do this I am writing this is in SQL Server?

```
select * 
from records 
where last record and lastest record is greater than 12 months.
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the `lag()` or `lead()` function.  This is available in SQL Server 2012+.

```
select r.*
from (select r.*,
             lag(createddate) over (partition by userid order by createddate) as last_createddate
      from records r
     ) r
where last_createddate is null or
      last_createddate < dateadd(year, -1, createddate);
```

In earlier versions of SQL Server, you can emulate the logic using `outer apply`, although the performance is often worse.